# iOS 10 how do I make the notification center start on the left card?

Tags: iphone, notifications, ios

I updated to iOS 10 and noticed that when I open the notification center (swipe top-down) it always starts on the right card, which I suppose is recent notifications.

It used to start on what's now the left card, which is more of a widget dashboard screen. How can I make it always start on the left card?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I recall that's how iOS 9 (and 8, I think) operated, too.

In any event there is no setting to change this behavior.

Comment: I feel like the previous notification center remembered which screen it was on... can someone with an older iOS version please verify?

Comment: No, iOS 9 and 8 remembered which one you left it on previously, and just went to that.